# Why is my wi-fi still not working?

Tags: wireless, drivers, realtek, ndiswrapper

i have 10.10, and have gotten ndiswrapper and the proper driver, it installed properly, but still my wi-fi isn't working. In terminal it say its disabled, but its enabled EVERYWHERE... even when I exited windows.

Right now i'm left to use an Ethernet cord and a second computer... please help. My windows isn't in good condition and I would love to switch to Ubuntu... but wi-fi is definitely a need. FYI, I have a toshiba satellite a505d-s6958 with the realtek rtl819[somehting something something]... but I have the driver from their webisite...   I really just need to get my wifi to work

Comment: We need the you to be more specific with the realtek rtl819(something) part in order to fix it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Comment: Found this googling the issue. It states there is a specific driver to be compiled manually. Still dont know if it solves the issue, but i seriously hope. Maybe someone around could make this solution a bit more friendly. http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-wireless-networking-41/firmware-for-realtek-8192-a-761714/page3.html

Answer (score 3):

You should not be using ndiswrapper, you should not be using the drivers from the realtek website and you should not be compiling things.

What we need to know is what hardware you have (exactly the kind!) and what the issue is from a FRESH install. Use lspci and report back in your question the output.

The problem a lot of time is that users follow strange, out of date and wrong headed advice on other websites and mess up their machines and it's hard to dig them out, but we will try and it starts with you giving us exact information.